# Calculating The Bearing And Compass Rose Direction Between Two Latitude / Longitude Coordinates

Tags: android, compass-geolocation

Does anyone know a tutorial for calculating the bearing/compass rose direction between two latitude/longitude coordinates with Android ?

Comment: A bunch of related maths here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 0):

Android's `Location` class provides methods for that, namely `bearingTo()` and `distanceTo()`.
To calcuate the declination, use the `MagneticField` class.